# How to refactor case statements with excessive nesting

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework

In many situations I find myself needing to pattern match on both a struct itself and its fields, and proceed to perform some further actions when some intermediate results are not empty.

However, the struct itself might be `nil` in the first place. This resulted in me writing multiple nested matches, e.g.

```
experiment = Repo.get(Experiment, experiment_id)

case experiment do
  nil ->
    # Error 1

  _ ->
    case experiment.active do
      false -> # Error 2
      true -> 
        case Repo.all(assoc(experiment, :experiment_results)) do
          [] -> # Error 3
          results -> # Do stuffs
    end
end
```

Ideally I would want to write code without so much nesting.

How can I refactor the code?

---

(Note that my original question was about pattern matching on a struct when it could be `nil`. My actual use case is broader than my original question suggested, thus I updated the question.)

The original code, to which AlekseiMatiushkin and Sheharyar's answers apply:

```
experiment = Repo.get(Experiment, experiment_id)

case experiment do
  nil ->
    :error

  _ ->
    case experiment.active do
      false -> :error
      true -> # Do stuffs
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use the [`with`](https://www.openmymind.net/Elixirs-With-Statement/) syntax. It essentially stipulates what the "happy path" should be, even when the path entails multiple relatively complex checks:

```
with experiment <- Repo.get(Experiment, id),
     {:nil_experiment, false} <- {:nil_experiment, is_nil(experiment)},
     experiment_results <- Repo.all(assoc(experiment, :experiment_results)),
     {:empty_results, false} <- {:empty_results, Enum.empty?(experiment_results)} do
do
  # Do stuffs with `experiment_results`
else
  {:nil_experiment, true} ->
     # Error message 1

  {:empty_results, true} ->
     # Error message 2

  _ ->
     # Unknown error
end
```

Comment: This is abusing [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) for performing `case` pattern matching with a ton of redundant local variables/atoms. It’s **clearly an anti-pattern** and one should never use this. The rule of thumb is “if you find yourself handling `else` clauses in `with`, something went wrong.” Instead, use `case` from my snippet with many clauses.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Right. Do you mean that the `else` part of `with` should normally only be used with one clause instead of multiple clauses? I don't think that is how it's designed to use though. Also, I agree with your solution if the code is only confined to checking `experiment`, but my use case actually more looks like this. See my updated code. I wonder how one would handle this case with `case` statements, since my happy path involves something more than just the `experiment` struct. I would like to hear your advice.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Even Michael Muskala apparently had an example where the `else` part contains multiple clauses: See the top comment at https://relistan.com/elixir-thoughts-on-the-with-statement

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think my original question was not totally accurate/broad enough for my use case. I have updated the question. I came across a talk which advocates the use of `with` over too much piping after asking the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CAqWHhMPjE&list=PLqj39LCvnOWaxI87jVkxSdtjG8tlhl7U6&index=35, and I think it is usually more generically applicable in such use cases, while `case` statement could apply to narrower cases.

Comment: Well, OK, now it’s a perfect use-case for `with` monadic behaviour. I am not a fortuneteller to read your mind though :)

Comment: FWIW, by your question update you obsoleted my answer, making it somewhat half-correct.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Haha thanks for agreeing with the pattern. Yeah my initial question was not asked accurately. Sorry for that. I'll edit the question so that it also shows my initial code.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with a direct pattern match.

```
Experiment
|> Repo.get(experiment_id)
|> case do
  %Experiment{active: true, other_attribute: :value} ->
    # do stuff
  _ ->
    :error
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**How about the [`&&`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#&&/2) short-circuit operator?**

```ex
if experiment && experiment.active && experiment.other do
  # do something
else
  :error
end
```

---

**You can also use [`cond`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#cond/1) to add more cases:**

```ex
cond do
  experiment && experiment.active && experiment.other ->
    # do something

  !experiment.active ->
    {:error, :inactive}

  is_nil(experiment) ->
    {:error, :experiment_is_nil}

  true ->
    {:error, :unknown}
end
```